# "sich bei etwas sicher sein" or "sich etwas[Gen.] sicher sein"

Tags: genitive

In a German text I had written, one of its sentences has been corrected as follows :

> Zum Beispiel schreibe ich Wörter, **bei deren** Aussprache ich mir nicht
>   sicher bin, zwischen eckigen Klammern.

In my original sentence, I had written :

> Zum Beispiel schreibe ich Wörter, **deren** Aussprache ich mir nicht
>   sicher bin, zwischen eckigen Klammern.

As far as I know, the correct expression is "sich etwas[Gen.] sicher sein". I don't understand the meaning of "bei" in this sentence and why it is necessary.

Could anyone please explain to me why it's "bei deren" and not just "deren" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there is a difference in meaning which may become more obvious when we shorten these sentences to:

> Ich bin mir bei der Aussprache <sup>Dat.</sup> sicher.

This is exactly what we want to say: *"I am confident on pronouncing"*.

> Ich bin mir der Aussprache <sup>Gen.</sup> sicher.

This may be taken as identical to the above but there is a different meaning when using genitive case: *"I am sure of a pronunciation."* In your examples above we make clear that we use the dative case by introducing the preposition *"bei"*.

This can also be seen in the following examples:

> - Er ist sich ihrer Liebe sicher. - *He is sure she will love him.*
>     Er ist sich bei ihrer Liebe sicher. - *He is sure her love is true.*
> - Sie fühlt sich ihres Einkommens sicher. - *She feels her income is safe.*
>     Sie fühlt sich bei ihrem Einkommen sicher. - *She feels safe with her income.*